# Using Sticky Kit jQuery plugin, but can't figure out how to use the 'offset_top' option?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, offset, sticky

Has anyone had any experience using the excellent **Sticky Kit jQuery** plugin? http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/

I can't figure out how to use the **'offset_top'** option? The documentation for the options is a bit vague, the example shown is below:

```
$("#sticky_item").stick_in_parent(options)
```

I guess I have to write something like this:

```
$("#sticky_item").stick_in_parent(offset_top)
```

But how do I specify the number of pixels I want to offset **#sticky_item** by?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 36):

Ah, figured it out.

To add a 20 pixel offset to #sticky_item do this:

```
$("#primary").stick_in_parent({offset_top: 20});
```